# What's the norm in the given space?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Currently I'm reading the paper by Pluta and Russo titled [Ternary operator categories](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ebrusso/prT*Cat071321.pdf).

According to section $1.2$ of the paper, an associative triple system  is a vector space $V$ with a trilinear map $(x,y,z) \to [x,y,z]$ of $V^3$ into $V$ and satisfies $[[x,y,z],u,v]=[x,y,[z,u,v]]= [x,[u,z,y],v]$. For a given normed associative triple system $M$, define $$E(M)=\operatorname{End}(M)\oplus\overline{End(M)}^{op}$$
Where the notation $\overline{V}$ for a complex vector space means that the scalar multiplication in $V$ is $(\lambda,v)=\overline{\lambda}v$, End($M$) denotes the space of endomorphisms of $M$ and $\overline{End(M)}^{op}$ denotes the opposite of $\overline{End(M)}$

> Can someone clarify me the norm in $E(M)$

Comment: Are the vector spaces finite dimensional? Do they have a norm? What is the norm you're looking for on $E(M)$ used for? You ask a question about a norm on $E(M)$ but nothing in what you've written before has anything to do with normed spaces, so I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: @CaptainLama: $ M$ is a normed space, thanks.

Comment: What is the sum in the definition of $E(M)$? It is the direct sum?

Comment: @QuantumSpace: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The paper is not clear on that, and I have no access to the references. I would tend to assume that the natural way to do this is to use the operator norm on $\operatorname{End}(M)$, namely
$$
\|\phi\|=\sup\{\|\phi(x)\|:\ x\in V,\ \|x\|=1\}, 
$$
and
$$
\|\phi\oplus\psi\|=\max\{\|\phi\|,\|\psi\|\}. 
$$